# How to split something by comma, put it into an array, and put the split array back into a string, then split by line back into an array?

Tags: java

I am making a Monte Carlo simulation for the Baseball coach at my school. What I'm trying to do currently is read in a text file using BufferedReader (that's a whole other problem in itself, but I can get around that) and then by split all of the lines by the return (I've already done that) but from there, I want to from each of those arrays that should have been created, I want to split each by comma, so then for each player on the baseball team, I would have one separate array for them.
Thanks!
- Parker

I wasn't really sure where to start, so I've gotten to where I said I've gotten to but got stuck so haven't really been able to try anything.

```
public Main() throws IOException {
    String[] playerstats = null;
    String playername = null;
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("MHS_Baseball_Season_Stats_19_csv.txt");
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    int lines = 0;
    String[] Playerstats = null;

    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        lines++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        playername = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("MHS_Baseball_Season_Stats_19_csv.txt")).get(i);
        playerstats = playername.split("\\R");
        for (int j = 0; j < playerstats.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(playerstats[j]);
            Playerstats = playerstats[j].split(",");
        }

    }
    System.out.println(Playerstats[148]);
    }
```

Comment: `String[] array = someString.split(”,”)`;

Comment: Thanks, maybe I've done this wrong, but it doesn't give me separate arrays. This works perfectly, but only for the last line. Thanks again.

Comment: You need an array of arrays since you want to read statistics for several players or even better a list of arrays if you are familiar with ArrayList

Comment: Instead of having two loops consider using only one while loop like this `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually fairly easy: Read the lines into a list, then convert each line into a list of its own by separating at commas. Your result should be a list of lists (I always encourage using lists over arrays).

```java
final String filename = "MHS_Baseball_Season_Stats_19_csv.txt";
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));
List<List<String>> playerStats = new ArrayList<>(lines.size());

for (String line : lines) {
    String[] lineValues = line.split(",");
    playerStats.add(Arrays.asList(lineValues));
}
```

Now the CSV file has been converted to a list of lists of Strings, so for example, to get the third column on the first row, you do

```java
String value = playerStats.get(0).get(2); // first row, third column
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses BufferedReader to read file and than an ArrayList to store each player statistics array

```
public Main() throws IOException {
    List<String[]> playerStats = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("MHS_Baseball_Season_Stats_19_csv.txt"))) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] stats = line.split(",");
            playerStats.add(stats);
        }
    }

    //example printing all stats for each player
    for (String[] stats : playerStats) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stats));
    }
    //example printing first element for each player
    for (int i = 0; i < playerStats.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(playerStats.get(i)[0]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You guys are absolutely amazing!